# TYPE_KEYGUARD only working on emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap app and I want to disable all buttons. For disable the Home button i use:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);     
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
 }
```

but it's only working in the Android emulator, I installed the apk file in a smartphone and a tablet but in the both of them i get the same error, the app stopped dialog.

Comment: `Window type: dialogs that the keyguard shows In multiuser systems shows on all users' windows.` I don't think that is what you really want. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG

Comment: I just want to disable the home button and the the recent apps button. I'm developing an app where if you want to exit the app you have to know a secret gesture or password.